# Solr query vs. filter query not working the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, solr

I have been using solr for a while now (acts_as_solr) , but just came across a very strange one I can't seem to get working.

I have a 'text' field lets call it

```
audience = [students, teachers, students_teachers, none]
```

when I send the query

```
q= audience:students
```

it returns only those with it set to students.

yet if I do

```
fq= audience:students
```

I get back results with both [students, students_teachers]

I have tried putting quotes, parens and all sorts around the filter query, but it seems like it is not honoring them as I would expect.  I am actually using a negation side of fq here, to hide from the user some results.

I am using solr 1.4.1

Any thoughts? I am about to change the options to unique words with no reuse.  Might be an issue with the _ 's in the names.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: what's the field type of `audience`?

Comment: audience is both _t and _s in acts_as_solr terms.  I was doing all the queries using the _t

Comment: Those are not field types... please check the solr schema.

Comment: Ok Ok, fair enough.  _t => text    and _s => string

Comment: cool, but those are still variable. What are the field type definitions?

Comment: Field: audience_t    which is dynamically createded from pattern: *_T   from there
Field Type: text
Fields: TEXT *_DISPLAY IGNORED_* *_T

Comment: I did end up removing the '_' from the available set of audience values, and it all started working.

Comment: Ok, but it seems you just fixed it by coincidence... if you're interested in an explanation post the field types.

Comment: where can I find the actual solr field types? we are using Acts_As_Solr so it is setting up dynamic fields for me.

Comment: search for `<fieldType>` in schema.xml

Comment: added in the field type named text

Answer (score 2):

WordDelimiterFilterFactory in your field type is probably generating the terms "students" and "teachers" from the string "students_teachers".

So when you search for "students", it also matches the string that originally was "students_teachers".

As an aside: Solr is a very configurable tool and can be quite complex, I recommend not treating it as a black box or you'll very probably have more and more of these "WTF moments".

Comment: but why is it different from q and fq? That is the part that seems strange to me.  I did things like fq= audience:(students)  fq= audience:'students'  it did not matter, got different results than q=audience:students  q=audience:(students)  q=audience:'students'

Comment: @MarkRedding : are you using dismax? can you check the Solr analysis tool? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-solr2/